# Prestashop 1.4 and multiple discounts. Which prevails?

Tags: prestashop

anyone could address me to solve the following issue?

In PS 1.4 I have a generic discount (6 pieces, 10% reduction). But it can be that I add a specific price discount starting from 1 piece, let's say 20%.

Now, PS applies the generic discount (10%) when I order 6 or more pieces, and the higher (20%) if I order from 1 to 5 pieces.

Basically, the more I buy, the more I pay...

the easiest solution would be to intercept the lines of code which actually add the prices to the cart. Where are they? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In the cart class, i'm not really familiar with 1.4, but i think there is a function called "checkDiscountValidity". I can see that all discount validations are made there, so override this method and add your own validations (adding a hook to a created module should be better in my opinion)